# How to Add Custom Json Schema Validators

Tags: json-schema-validator, light-4j

We are using the [light4j json schema validator](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator) in our project.
Version `1.0.36`

Is it possible to add custom validators like ISO8601 time/duration min and max for example? If so how do you add custom validation?

We realize these would not be part of the json schema standard, but we're just using it to validate our configuration json internally.

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed in the issues forum and a lot of users have added their customized validators. Let me know if you still have any questions.

https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator/issues/32